# IIS Redirect folder with and without a trailing slash

Tags: iis, http-redirect

I have a redirect that I'm working on.

< match url="^/videos" ignoreCase="true"/>

It works when I go to: www.mysite.com/videos/ .  But it doesn't work when I go to www.mysite.com/videos

I can't write a rule to force the trailing slash.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

< match url="^/videos(/)?$" ignoreCase="true"/>